# Server has invalid Kerberos principal: hdfs/XXXX@XXX

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, kerberos, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using kafka hdfs connector to stream data to HA enabled kerberized hadoop cluster.
While connecting I am getting the error

```
Server has invalid Kerberos principal: hdfs/namenode_hostname@CORP
```

I have configured below kerberos config for hdfs connector

```
hdfs.authentication.kerberos=true
connect.hdfs.principal=abc
connect.hdfs.keytab=/etc/security/keytabs/abc.keytab
hdfs.namenode.principal=hdfs/hdfs_namespace@CORP
```

The issue seems to be with the `hdfs.namenode.principal` value.
When I use active name node host name instead of HA namespace it works fine but on using the namespace it fails with the above mentioned error.
Since this is an HA enable hadoop cluster we don't want to hardcode the hostname in the connector prop.

Hadoop configuration in hdfs-site.xml is as below

```
 <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>hdfs/_HOST@CORP</value>
  </property>
```

Could you help me to figure out what might be the issue here ?

Comment: Your error doesn't match the configuration file. If you want the nameservice, though for HA, then you must mention the nameservice and the 2 namenodes in the hdfs-site for Connect

Comment: @cricket_007 yes in hdfs-site its already configured with 2 namenode and nameservice , and the cluster is HA .Does hadoop substitutes _HOST in kerberos principal with namenode or namespace ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think if it replaced anything, it would be the host of client process (connect server). If you actually put _HOST in the principal, though, I think that's wrong and needs to be an actual value in the KDC. For instance, if you you're able to run `hdfs dfs -ls` from the Connect Server after a kinit with that keytab file, and it works, then Connect shouldn't have any problems